# PrimeFaces ImageCropper display crop region dimensions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a jsf application to crop images using PrimeFaces 6.2 ImageCropper. I would like to display the dimensions of the cropping region (e.g. 500 x 500 pixels) as a text field below the image, and have the text field dimensions update appropriately as the user drags the edges of the region.

My approach to achieving this was to first create fields that maintain the values of the crop region dimensions in the `cropBean`. Then add a `valueChangeListener` tag in the ImageCropper to trigger a method in the `cropBean` to update the crop region dimensions. Here's a small portion of the code I'm using:

XHTML Portion:

```
<p:imageCropper value="#{cropBean.croppedImage}"
                    image="myImage.jpg"
                    initialCoords="0,0,#{cropBean.originalWidth}, #{cropBean.originalHeight}"
                    update=":mainContainer newDimensions"
                    valueChangeListener="#{cropBean.updateCropDimensions}" />

<h:outputText id="newDimensions"
                value="New Dimensions: #{cropBean.cropWidth} x #{cropBean.cropHeight}"
                style="font-style: italic" />
```

CropBean Portion:

```
private CroppedImage croppedImage;
private int cropWidth = 0;
private int cropHeight = 0;

public void updateCropDimensions() {
        cropWidth = croppedImage.getWidth();
        cropHeight = croppedImage.getHeight();
}
```

(I've also added getters and setters for the fields and verified that the cropping works)

However the `valueChangeListener` does not seem to be calling the `updateCropDimensions` method. Anyone know where I'm going wrong or have another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the dimensions to the user, you don't need to update server side bean properties `cropWith` and `cropHeight`. You can remove the `valueChangeListener` and directly display `croppedImage` properties `width` and `height`:

```
<h:form id="frm1">
    <p:imageCropper id="imageCropper" value="#{cropBean.croppedImage}"
         image="myImage.jpg" widgetVar="cropper"
         initialCoords="0,0,#{cropBean.originalWidth}, #{cropBean.originalHeight}"
         update=":mainContainer newDimensions"
         valueChangeListener="#{cropBean.updateCropDimensions}" />

    <h:outputText id="newDimensions"
         value="New Dimensions: #{cropBean.croppedImage.width} x #{cropBean.croppedImage.height}"
         style="font-style: italic" />
    <p:commandButton value="submit" update="dimensions" />
</h:form>
```

This will update the dimension display on each submission.
If you additionally want to display the currently selected dimension while the user is editing her selection, you can't do this via AJAX because `p:imageCropper` is not an AJAX enabled component. Additionally this would be much overhead creating a new `CroppedImage` instance on every user interaction.

Instead you could do this via JavaScript and override an internal method of the `p:imageCropper` widget. This of course introduces the risk of failure with future versions of PrimeFaces and might require maintenance:

Simply add (and understand) this JavaScript somewhere below the `p:imageCropper` and note that I have added a `id` and a `widgetVar` attribute to your `p:imageCropper`:

```
<h:outputScript>

// tweak the image cropper as soon as the image has been loaded
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('frm1:imageCropper_image')).on('load',
    function() {
        var cropper = PF('cropper');

        // backup original saveCoords function
        cropper.saveCoordsOrig = cropper.saveCoords;

        cropper.saveCoords = function(box) {
            // invoke original function
            this.saveCoordsOrig(box);

            // update the dimension display:    
            $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('frm1:newDimensions')).html(box.w + ' x ' + box.h);
        }
});
</h:outputScript>
```